# Is it possible to determine the classname of an outer class from an instance of an anonymous inner class

Tags: java, reflection, slf4j

I have a somewhat atypical logging situation where I want to write a log message on behalf of an outer class when only provided the instance of an anonymous inner class. I'm using slf4j.

Lets say i have a class:

```
public abstract class AFoo implements IFoo
```

Then I have an outer class that has a field with an abstract inner *IFoo* class:

```
public class Outer {
    protected IFoo myFoo = new AFoo() { }
}
```

Third, I have some utility class to generate some log message:

```
public SomeFooLoggerUtil {
    public static writeLogMessagesForFoo(IFoo somefoo) {
        Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(somefoo.getClass());
    }
}
```

Inside *writeLogMessagesForFoo*, what I want to do is say "if *somefoo* is an instance of an anonymous inner class, then use its outer class instead". So if somefoo is the in-line abstract AFoo from Outside, then Outside.class will be the logger used instead of AFoo$1.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Class.getEnclosingClass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getEnclosingClass--) to get the outer class. If classes can be nested multiple levels, just loop till you hit the top. For example:

```
static Class<?> getOutermostClass(Class<?> clazz) {
    while (clazz.getEnclosingClass() != null) {
        clazz = clazz.getEnclosingClass();
    }
    return clazz;
}

public static writeLogMessagesForFoo(IFoo somefoo) {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getOutermostClass(somefoo.getClass()));
}
```

Comment: That is incorrect. getDeclaringClass returns null here

Comment: You're right, I didn't realize anonymous classes are a [special case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9360115/1553851). Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

What you are finding is `getEnclosingClass`.

Comment: And the `getDeclaringClass` is to get the outer class of inner class (not anonyous). But in that case `getEnclosingClass` also works, so you can always use `getEnclosingClass`.